# What is the the etymology and origin of the word/name Calvus?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, etymology, names

Doing research ([the question was also asked here as well](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38591/%E2%80%A6)) I came across the name having a French origin meaning ["bald"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/calvin).  However, I also came across that the name has a connection to the word/name ["Chauvin"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chauvinism?ref=etymonline_crossreference). Does the name Calvin etymology just mean bald as in, balding of the hair? Is/was there a deeper meaning such as being empty, bereft, or lacking substance?  How does the name/word relate to Chauvin?

Thank you.

Comment: cross-posting https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38591/what-is-the-the-etymological-origin-of-the-name-calvin

Comment: @יהודה Cross-posting is considered rude on Stack Exchange sites, especially when not mentioned. Then people helping you duplicate their efforts, not knowing of each other. Also readers who end up seeing one of your posts do not know of their siblings where they might find answers from different perspectives. Please edit links to the other versions into your question and edit the question so that it focuses more on the Latin side of things. Questions like this are welcome on this site, but we greatly appreciate transparency about cross-posting – and waiting a week before doing so.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta First I would like to apologize for whatever bad vibes I brought forth.  I am new to the "StackExchange Community" and am not too familiar with the written and unwritten etiquette.  My reasoning was just looking for sites that dealt with etymology based upon the name/word "Calvin".  Seeing how it has heavy roots in French and Latin (heavy usage in English as well) led me to inquire from the different avenues.  I appreciate the advice and will incorporate it moving forward. Be blessed beloved.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfectly normal for a new user not to know the etiquette thoroughly. I'm glad to see that you have the right attitude of willing to learn. I look forward to seeing more questions from you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name *Chauvin* (and the English form *Calvin*) is from the diminutive of the French *chauve* which means *bald*. According to the *[Trésor de la langue française](http://stella.atilf.fr)*, *chauve* comes from the Latin *calvus*.

According to Michiel de Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages*, the origin of *calvus* is attributed to the Proto-Indo-European
*klH‑e/ou̯o‑‎:

[image]

The basic meaning is that of a *bald head*, and thus has no deeper meaning associated with it as suggested by your question.

Comment: The text that you pasted is from de Vaan, not from the Trésor.

Comment: @fdb. I edited it to make that more clear.